# Number of solutions of $2^{\cos x}=|\sin x|$

Tags: functions, trigonometry

I have tried a lot on solving this question, but i m unable to simplify the expression.

> Find the total number of solutions of $2^{\cos x}=|\sin x|$ where $x\in[-2π,5π]$.

See the answer below for the OP's thoughts.

Comment: It cannot be simplified. Did you plot the two functions to get an idea?

Comment: Hint: there's a solution at $\pi/2$. Second hint: both are even functions.

Comment: Also, I recommend that you study [our guide to new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619). The way your question is written, brief and to the point as it is, presses people's buttons here because it has the air of trying to outsource homework. Take my first comment as one way of providing additional context and sharing your own thoughts.

Comment: @Jyrki Excellent way of putting it! I've been having a hard time expressing that feeling

Comment: Thank you Jyrki for your support, I'll surely read that guide, coz I m new here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to bother you guys I finally did it myself

The graph of 2^cosx will cut |sin x| two times in interval of π , so total solutions will be 2×(5+2)= 14.

[image]

Comment: Presumably you mean *in an interval of the form $[n\pi,(n+1)\pi]$*. Good job, you see it wasn't too hard! Now, depending on the course you are in, it may or may not be expected that you justify this observation. By properties of continuous functions you can (a bit more rigorously) show that there are at least this many solutions. To prove that there are no more solutions you (probably) need to bring in the concepts of increasing/decreasing functions, or derivatives. It is still difficult for us to tell whether that is expected. Because we know nothing about the course you are in:-) Tell us!

Comment: I m currently in class 12th and studying for competitive exams